I want to change the cells of the table on the Grafana screen one by one
I have a table located in a Grafana screen. When I click on a cell in this table I want to be able to edit it and then when I press the save button the variable I updated in the cell will also be updated in the database. How can I do this in Grafana? When I did some research, it turned out that it could be done with Grafana Data manipulation plugin, but I couldn't understand it. can you help me.
For example, I get the variables of the status table in my postgresql database. I want to change the value in line id148 to offline.

